# Create TableLayoutPanel with controls

Tags: c#

I have a tablelayoutpanel with 2 rows.
The 1st row contains only Labels in each column and the 2nd contains a combobox in the 1st column and 4 textboxes in the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th columns and 2 buttons in the 2 last columns. I want when I click the Add button it creates dynamically another row with the same architecture than the 2nd. I work on windows form and I'm novist. You can see my form on the image

[image: 1]

**code:**

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox Cmb = new ComboBox();

            Cmb.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            Cmb.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            Cmb.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Popup;
            Cmb.FormattingEnabled = true;
            //Cmb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 47);
            Cmb.Name = "comboBox1";
            Cmb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(289, 24);
            //Cmb.TabIndex = 5;

            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));

            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Cmb, 0, 2);
        }
```

Comment: Do not use a LayoutPanel it has very limited capabilities.  Instead use a Main Panel and then add subPanels (or controls) so you have better options.

Comment: I have any idea for what you suggest.

Comment: You are trying to mimic a grid view. Why not use a `DataGridView` or corresponding 3rd party grid view. There are very powerful products out there, including grids having complex built-in filter capabilities.

Comment: I said very clearly : DO NOT USE tableLayoutPanel!!!  Use Panel instead.  The layout panel will not do what you want!!!

Comment: Thank you Olivier for your contribution, but I think if it is possible to do what I want I prefer  it.

Comment: Ok  jdweng , I will try your solution.